# Not a valid Win32 application... Python, PyInstaller, Windows7

Tags: python, pyinstaller

How can I know if I build a 32bit application or 64bit application?

I have created .exe with Pyinstaller and it works fine on my computer (Win7 Ultimate 64), when I try to run the same exe on Virtual Machine (Win7 Home Premium 64) I get: Error 193 not a valid Win32 application.

Python 2.7 32bit
PyInstaller 2.1 (I think also 32)

So isn't this 32bit application that should work fine on 64 too?

Comment: To check whether an exe is 32 or 64 bits: see [here](http://superuser.com/questions/358434/how-to-check-if-a-binary-is-32-or-64-bit-on-windows)

Comment: Perhaps your file simply was corrupted during transfer to the vm ? Compare the original and the copy or open the copy in notepad or a hexviewer and search for signs of a valid exe.

Comment: It is 32 bit application, thank you for advice.
I have compared them they are the same.. :(

Comment: Perhaps it's linked with 64 bit DLLs

Comment: That's what I first thought, I use mfc100.dll, msvcp100.dll and msvcr100.dll but I can not find version for 32,64. I think it's the same thing. 
@DavidHeffernan

Comment: You say you compared the file before/after the transfer... how? I would install e.g. HashTab and check the MD5 before and after the transfer. It certainly sounds like corruption.

Comment: I made this work with python 2.7.10  64bit, I changed nothing except python for 64bit... So I guess it was some kind of mismatch, thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

uninstall using "python27\Scripts>pip uninstall pyinstall" and Reinstall  "python27\Scripts>pip install pyinstall" worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Use pip to uninstall then reinstall pyinstaller. The first time I used pyinstaller it worked, since then it corrupted. Reinstalling fixed the issue.