# Unable to run exe file of a CVXPy code compiled by Pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, cvxpy

I've wrote a simple code that solves optimization problem using the [CVXPy](http://www.cvxpy.org/) library.

```
from cvxpy import Variable, Minimize, Problem, abs

c = [20, 20, 50]
k = [-0.25, -0.15, -0.25, -0.35, -0.15, -0.25]
xbr_1, xbr_2 = Variable(1), Variable(1)
mra_1, mra_2 = Variable(1), Variable(1)

# Objective function
objective = Minimize(c[0] * abs(xbr_1) + c[1] * abs(xbr_2) +
                     c[2] * abs(mra_1) + c[2] * abs(mra_2))
# Right hand side of inequalities
rhs_1 = 1500
rhs_2 = 1400
lhs_1 = (k[0] * xbr_1 + k[1] * xbr_2 + k[2] * mra_1)
lhs_2 = (k[3] * xbr_1 + k[4] * xbr_2 + k[5] * mra_2)
# Problem constraints
constraints = [lhs_1 <= rhs_1,
               lhs_2 <= rhs_2,
               xbr_1 <= 1000,
               xbr_2 <= 1000]
prob = Problem(objective, constraints)

# The optimal objective is returned by prob.solve().
result = prob.solve()
```

I would like to create an exe file using [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/), I have version 3.1.1. The log of the compiling proces is [enclosed](http://0.dl.webshare.cz/7003/5m06q35z22/524288000/eyJhZGRyIjoiODkuMTExLjkyLjEzNSIsInZhbGlkX3RvIjoxNDg1NDI1OTUyLCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxNDIwMTAsImZyZWUiOjB9/115945ed9cd7f787598c95a3402e7899/warnbrute_prog.txt). The compiling proces finishes successfuly.

When I try to execute the compiled file i get the following error message:

```
C:\_Studna>brute_prog.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 47, in <module>
  File "C:\_Studna\Python\python-2.7.10.amd64\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller-3.1.
1\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\_Studna\Python\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\win32com\__init__.py", line 5,
 in <module>
    import win32api, sys, os
  File "C:\_Studna\Python\python-2.7.10.amd64\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller-3.1.
1\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in load_module
    module = imp.load_module(fullname, fp, filename, ext_tuple)
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 not a valid Win32 application.
pyi_rth_win32comgenpy returned -1
```

Anyone can provide some suggestions? I have found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32991315/not-a-valid-win32-application-python-pyinstaller-windows7) that might be relevant to this topic.

Comment: What parameters of pyinstaller did you use for compilation?

Comment: i just use onefile option, i.e.,  `-F opt.py`